# Data collections - multi-level of categorisation, which collection to use?

Tags: java, collections

I need to define my data collections in multiple levels of categories e.g. cars \ suv \ toyota \ hydrid \ purple.

Later I have to visualize this data-set in some form of tree-view/grid with collapsible/expandable sections.

I am not so aware with multi-level collections so I am wondering what type of collections I should use?

Anyone has a recommendation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. An illustration would be welcome. At first glance the best fit is simply a tree

Comment: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/group#multi  multi level grouping

Comment: or https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Multilevel-Collapsible-Table-Rows-Tabelizer/

Comment: Then it seems like you just need to implement a tree don't you?

Comment: I want columns too, not just a single value. the rowgroup in datatables but then with more than 2 levels is what I want

Comment: Can't you just store the values of the columns in an object in each node of the tree (or only in leaves depending on what you need)?